# Given two public keys and e to find a private keys

Tags: python, security, cryptography, rsa

I am taking a cyber security class recently. I was wondering if I was given two public keys, n1 and n2 (and e the exponent)--how would one generate a private key for n1? In this scenario, n1 and n2 share primes.

I know I need to use

> =^(−1)  (−1)(−1)

and I also know since they shares primes (p), I could find their corresponding q easily. However, I was stuck in calculating d.

```py
def calculate_private_key(n1, n2, e):
    # Step 1: Calculate the prime factor (p) shared by n1 and n2
    p = gcd(n1, n2)
    # Step 2: Calculate the remaining factors (q1 and q2)
    q1 = n1 // p
    q2 = n2 // p

    # Step 3: Calculate the totient (phi) of the modulus (n)
    phi1 = (p - 1) * (q1 - 1)
    phi2 = (p - 1) * (q2 - 1)

    # Step 4: Calculate the modular inverse 
    d1 = find_modular_inverse(e, phi1)
    d2 = find_modular_inverse(e, phi2)

    q1_inv = find_modular_inverse(q1, p)
    q2_inv = find_modular_inverse(q2, p)

    d = (d1 * q1 * q2_inv + d2 * q2 * q1_inv) % (p * q1 *q2)

    return d
```

I assume CRT was needed to solve d and this is what I wrote, but the answer was wrong. I was wondering where did it go wrong. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. I was wondering did I implemented the top formula wrongly.

EDIT:
To be more clear gcd/find_modular_inverse are self defined function.

```py
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def extended_euclidean(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a, 1, 0
    else:
        gcd, x, y = extended_euclidean(b, a % b)
        return gcd, y, x - (a // b) * y

def find_modular_inverse(q2, p):
    gcd, x, _ = extended_euclidean(p, q2)
    if x < 0:
        x += p
    return x
```

Comment: Are you using a library for `gcd` and `find_modular_inverse`?

Comment: no, both are self defined function.

Comment: I did not clearly understand you question, however, you cannot find `d` with `e` and `n` alone. Here `e` is the public exponent `n` is the modulus and we call the pair `(e,n)` as the public key. Your notation is out of standards.

Comment: Maybe I should add e is the same as well. As n1/n2 are both modulus taht shares a prime.

Comment: shares prime is also not clear. share one primes or two?

Comment: I cannot understand you clearly either. Your goal as I understand you say is to find the private key of `n1`. You have `n1= p1*q1` , `n2= p2*q2` , `e`, `both phis` and `both ds`. What is the `d` you are returning from `calculate_private_key` function? I mean if you need the private key of `n1`, then you got it from `d1`...

Comment: They share one prime factor namely p, that's another place that I am stuck in, since n1 and n2 are provided in the question and will be used.

Comment: You are finished after step 4. `d1` and `d2` are the decrypt exponents for `n1` and `n2`, they will not be the same.

Comment: Yes, but according to question, I should be able to use d1 and d2 to find the d

Comment: There is no d. The decrypt exponents of n1 and n2 are different.

Comment: Or, if you only want to find d1, then you have found it. The only operation you need n2 for is the gcd calculation to recover the common prime.

Comment: Yes, that's what i was thinking, but it seems that the key was far off than the answer.

Comment: If they share only one prime than just take gcd ([python math has it](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_gcd.asp)) then you have p and q_1 and q_2, now rest easy

Comment: Thanks guys, I was stuck in the loop that I must use n1 and n2 and did not realize I made a silly mistake. I solved it

Answer (score 0):

I was just being silly, n1 and n2 was not related in getting d.

Comment: It is better to post the working code here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).